# Drop row from a data frame that overlaps with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I have a first dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'subject':[1,4,8,1,2,6,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,2,3,4,5,8,9,10], 
                    'trial':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]}) 

print(df1)

    subject  trial
0         1      1
1         4      1
2         8      1
3         1      2
4         2      2
5         6      2
6         9      2
7        11      2
8        12      2
9        13      2
10       14      2
11       15      2
12       16      2
13       17      2
14       18      2
15       19      2
16       20      2
17       21      2
18       22      2
19       23      2
20       24      2
21        2      3
22        3      3
23        4      3
24        5      3
25        8      3
26        9      3
27       10      3
```

And a second dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'subject':[2,3], 
                    'trial':[12,4]})   

print(df2)

   subject  trial
0        2     12
1        3      4
```

I would like to remove for subject 2, all the trials until trial 12 included (trial 1,4,8,1,2,6,9,11,12 for subject 2) and for subject 3 until trial 4 included (trial 2,3,4 for subject 3)

Would it be possible to do it comparing both DataFrames or with map and drop from a dictionary?

Comment: The name of df2 seems off

Comment: seems like you have swapped trial and subject in second df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use [set](https://realpython.com/python-sets/#operating-on-a-set) operations

1. `groupby('subject')` and `agg(set)` onto `trial`
2. `.join` the two dataframes
3. Create a `set` of `trail_n` using `range(x + 1)` since the objective is to remove all previous trials.
4. Take the `difference` of the two `sets`
5. Convert the result back to a `list` and `explode`, if you want.

   - `explode` is available from pandas 0.25

```py
import pandas as pd

# data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'subject': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                    'trial': [1,4,8,1,2,6,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,2,3,4,5,8,9,10]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'subject': [2, 3], 
                    'trial': [12, 4]})   

# set subject as the index in df2
df2.set_index('subject', inplace=True)

# for df1 groupby subject and agg set onto trial
df1g = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby('subject')['trial'].agg(set))

|   subject | trial                                                                |
|----------:|:---------------------------------------------------------------------|
|         1 | {8, 1, 4}                                                            |
|         2 | {1, 2, 6, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24} |
|         3 | {2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10}                                               |


# join the dataframes
df_join = df1g.join(df2, rsuffix='_n')

|   subject | trial                                                                |   trial_n |
|----------:|:---------------------------------------------------------------------|----------:|
|         1 | {8, 1, 4}                                                            |       nan |
|         2 | {1, 2, 6, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24} |        12 |
|         3 | {2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10}                                               |         4 |

# this is required because set & range don't work with nan
df_join.trial_n.fillna(0, inplace=True)

# convert trial_n to a set; int is required because range doesn't work with float
df_join.trial_n = df_join.trial_n.apply(lambda x: set(range(int(x)+1)))

# take the set difference
df_join['remains'] = df_join.trial - df_join.trial_n

|   subject | trial                                                                | trial_n                                    | remains                                          |
|----------:|:---------------------------------------------------------------------|:-------------------------------------------|:-------------------------------------------------|
|         1 | {8, 1, 4}                                                            | {0}                                        | {8, 1, 4}                                        |
|         2 | {1, 2, 6, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24} | {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12} | {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24} |
|         3 | {2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10}                                               | {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}                            | {8, 9, 10, 5}                                    |

# create df_final & convert remains back to a list so explode can be used
df_final = pd.DataFrame(df_join.remains.map(list).map(sorted))

|   subject | remains                                          |
|----------:|:-------------------------------------------------|
|         1 | [1, 4, 8]                                        |
|         2 | [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24] |
|         3 | [5, 8, 9, 10]                                    |

# explode the lists
df_final = df_final.explode('remains')

|   subject |   remains |
|----------:|----------:|
|         1 |         1 |
|         1 |         4 |
|         1 |         8 |
|         2 |        13 |
|         2 |        14 |
|         2 |        15 |
|         2 |        16 |
|         2 |        17 |
|         2 |        18 |
|         2 |        19 |
|         2 |        20 |
|         2 |        21 |
|         2 |        22 |
|         2 |        23 |
|         2 |        24 |
|         3 |         5 |
|         3 |         8 |
|         3 |         9 |
|         3 |        10 |
```